# Conclude behaviour of holomorphic function on interior from behaviour on boundary - by the example of Theta function

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, theta-functions

## Actual Problem

*I feel like by attempting to transfer my problem to a more general form it suffered a lot of important detail. So here i present to you my actual problem. It's part of a proof in an article about Theta functions and this particular aspect is stated without any explanation:*

$ k':=\left(\frac{\vartheta_{01}(0;w)}{\vartheta_{00}(0;w)}\right)^2 $ (I use notations like on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function))

Remark: $k'$ is holomorphic on the whole upper half of the complex plane.

The article's author shows that $k'$ maps the red line in below figure to the green lines (positive real and imaginary axis). **And then he does the - for me - vague implication that $k'$ maps left side's grey area to right side's grey area.**
[image: $k'$ maps red line to green line]

Could anybody explain why?
PS: I could provide the article but it's in german :\

> ## Old Version of my question
>
> ### Idea
>
> Does a holomorphic function map the boundary of a set to the boundary of another set? Are all interior points mapped to interior
>   points of a set, which is bounded by the mapped boundary?
>
> ### Conditions
>
> Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on open set $G$ and $D$ be a connected subset of $G$. Let's say the boundary $\partial D$ of
>   $D$ is mapped to the positiv imaginary axis and the positiv real axis
>   by $f$, i.e. $ f(\partial D)=\left\{ z\in\mathbb{C}: Re(z)=0,
> > Im(z)\geq0 \right\}\cup \left\{ z\in\mathbb{C}: Im(z)=0,Re(z)\geq0
> > \right\} $. So $f(\partial D)$ is a boundary to the first quadrant of
>   the complex plane: $f(\partial D)=\partial \left\{ z\in\mathbb{C}:
> > Re(z)\geq0, Im(z)\geq0 \right\}$
>
> ### Question
>
> Is the map of an interior point $z$ of $D$ by $f$ an element of the first quadrant of the complex plane? $ \forall z \in D:
> > f(z)\in\left\{ z\in\mathbb{C}: Re(z)\geq0, Im(z)\geq0 \right\} $?

Comment: Added the actual problem. Tought there must be an easy generalization for holomorphic functions but - as @hagenvoneitzen prooved - I am missing something!

Comment: That's the situation mentioned in [my comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916916/conclude-behaviour-of-holomorphic-function-on-interior-from-behaviour-on-boundar#comment1892969_916953). The function $k'$ is injective on the indicated hyperbolic triangle (I forgot pretty much everything about $\vartheta$-functions, so I have no idea whether that's obvious or not), and maps some point of the interior to the first quadrant. Then it follows that it maps the triangle to the quadrant (biholomorphically). The required ingredients are injectivity, and the openness of $k'$.

Comment: @danielfischer Yes injectivity would totally solve my problem. But I haven't found any source for proove. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know. It would suffice to see that $k'$ leaves out some point in the complement of the closed quadrant, then the openness implies that $k'$ maps the triangle to the quadrant. But the injectivity of $k'$ probably can be seen from the mapping properties, in particular the functional equations, of the $\vartheta$-functions.

Answer (score 2):

Not Necessarily. If $f$ maps $\partial D$ to the two positive axes, then so does $g\colon z\mapsto i f(z)^3$. Note that if $f(z)$ is in the first quadrant, then $g(z)$ is not.

Your problem is that $f(\partial D)$ is the boundary of two distinct (simply) connected regions. (I added "simply" in parentheses because you did not even require $D$ to be simply connected, which leaves a lot of liberty)

Comment: Thank's for the answer. Let's say $D$ is simply connected. What does that imply?

Comment: If I could show that there is a $z\in D$ such that $f(z)$ is in the first quadrant, would that be enough?

Comment: @linksideal Let $D$ be the first quadrant, and consider $z \mapsto z^5$. If you require that $f$ be injective, that would change things.